# Can I get localized abbreviations for time parameters with C# in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, localization

I'm writing for ASP.NET using C# and I was wondering if it's possible to get the following words in their localized form (preferably abbreviated)?

- Second
- Minute
- Hour
- Day
- Week
- Month
- Year

Comment: What would be the benefit of this?  Even if you had the translations, you couldn't use them to construct localized date-time strings.

Comment: I'm writing a function that should show time span with the most significant value by converting it from minutes. For instance, if I have 0.5 it should return "30s" for English, but if I have 525949.0 it should return "1yr", etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can localize some time parts using:

- CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName
- CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedDayName
- CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName
- CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName

I've build a custom implementation **TimeCalendar** with the format provider **ITimeFormatter** (method *GetDuration*) in my [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET). It's using resource file to localize the time parts.

Answer (score 4):

The .Net runtime does not include localized versions of these words. You will need to provide them yourself.

Comment: Yes, it looks like I'll have to add them in the resource.